# Is it possible to run everything without sudo?

Tags: sudo

Ignoring security reasons, is it possible to do? And how to do it?

Comment: ```"sudo to always work without prompting you for a password"```, that.

Answer (score 0):

(ignoring security reasons)if you are just annoyed typing the password then just:

`sudo -i`

or

`sudo -s`

or

`sudo su`